# C++ Perfect Function Forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591832/perfect-forwarding-in-c03) question.

A 2002 [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm) on the function forwarding problem in C++ makes the following observation:

> This is the method currently employed
>   by Boost.Bind and Boost.Lambda:
>
> ```
> template<class A1, class A2, class A3> void f(A1 & a1, A2 & a2, A3 & a3)
> {
>     return g(a1, a2, a3);
> }
> ```
>
> Its main deficiency is that it cannot
>   forward a non-const rvalue. The
>   argument deduction creates a non-const
>   reference, and the reference cannot
>   bind to the argument. This makes
>   innocent examples as
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     f(1, 2, 3);
> }
> ```
>
> fail (violates C1).

I see that the call fails, but is the explanation correct? Are not the literals 1, 2, 3 const rvalues?

Comment: Calling `f<const int, const int, const int>(1,2,3)` would work ok. That's basically why they are referring to the rvalues as 'non-const' deducable.

Comment: @LumpN, `f<const int, const int, const int>(1,2,3)` does indeed work. So is the problem that type deduction cannot deduce `const int` from a primitive literal?

Comment: If I recall correctly move semantics + variadic templates should now allow perfect forwarding (C++0x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Are not the literals 1, 2, 3 const rvalues?`

No, they are just rvalues of type int. According to the C++ standard, rvalues of primitive types cannot be const-qualified.

The call fails because they are ***rvalues*** - non-const references cannot be bound to rvalues.

The call would be OK if the functions took `const A1 &, const A2&, const A3&`, but in this case the function wouldn't be able to modify the arguments.

***Edit:*** Reference to my first statement from the C++ 2003 standard : (3.10.9)

> Class rvalues can have cv-qualified
>   types; non-class rvalues always have
>   cv-unqualified types. Rvalues shall
>   always have complete types or the void
>   type; in addition to these types,
>   lvalues can also have incomplete
>   types.

Comment: imho it much more practical to say `Ref(x)` when one needs modification, than to say `Value(x)` whenever one needs to supply value. i.e., formal arguments better be `T const&`.

Comment: So when the author says "cannot forward a non-const rvalue" he means "rvalue of primitive type int"?

Comment: @ThomasMcLead: No, the author says what he means: "non-const rvalues". Rvalues of non-class types, including primitive types, are always non-const, so the rule applies to them too